# executing SELECT query is not switching environment to new table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database with 2 tables: A1 and A2

When I click on A1 table, table is shown in browsing mode (executes query SELECT * FROM A1)

When I edit query (click on Inline), and write SELECT * FROM A2, it show results in table under query but it doesn't SWITCH 'environment' to Table A2 ???? I am stil in Table1. so, if want to click on SQL or Search Tab, it is still using A1 , instead A2.

This was normally 'switching' in my last phpmyadmin 3.3.9

Now I am in 4.2.5 and this is not working any more.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting; in my tests (starting on `actor` and manually changing to `category`) the highlighted/selected table in the navigation pane (left side of the screen) does change:

[image]

but the table that the tabs link to doesn't properly update:

[image]

I just [opened a ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1536/) about it.